# How can I use Python to download Qualtrics Survey responses via the Qualtrics API

Tags: python, api, qualtrics

**Overview**

I have found some Python code online which should allow me to download Qualtrics survey responses, however, there are aspects of the code which I would like to change for my specific needs. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work without breaking everything. The full code is included at the bottom.

**My goals are as follows -**

1. Connect to Qualtrics via the API and begin downloading a specific surveys responses
2. Display the download percentage with a maximum of 1 decimal place, as it downloads
3. Save the downloaded file as a .csv (zipped)

**Current issues faced**

1. The code already displays the download percentage, however, there are a crazy number of decimal places. I have tried rounding the value and then converting it to a string, which seems to work most of the time but occasionally the download percentage starts at something > 0 (no idea why, perhaps unrelated to round/converting)

---

```
        print("Download is " + str(round(requestCheckProgress)) + " complete")
```

---

2. The code I found online will try to extract the .csv file once it has downloaded. This is NOT what I want, as I plan to email the .csv to someone once it's downloaded (it will be too large to email once extracted). Unfortunately, I don't know how to just save the file somewhere
3. I want to save the file to the users (not necessarily me) downloads folder

The full code is below, thanks for any help you can -

---

```
import requests
import zipfile
import json
import io
import os

# Setting user Parameters
apiToken = "" #I will replace this
surveyId = "" #I will replace this
fileFormat = "csv"
dataCenter = "" #I will replace this

# Setting static parameters
requestCheckProgress = int(0)
progressStatus = "in progress"
baseUrl = "https://{0}.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/".format(dataCenter)
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-api-token": apiToken,
    }

# Step 1: Creating Data Export
downloadRequestUrl = baseUrl
downloadRequestPayload = '{"format":"' + fileFormat + '","surveyId":"' + surveyId + '"}'
downloadRequestResponse = requests.request("POST", downloadRequestUrl, data=downloadRequestPayload, headers=headers)
progressId = downloadRequestResponse.json()["result"]["id"]
print(downloadRequestResponse.text)

# Step 2: Checking on Data Export Progress and waiting until export is ready
while requestCheckProgress < 100 and progressStatus != "complete":
    requestCheckUrl = baseUrl + progressId
    requestCheckResponse = requests.request("GET", requestCheckUrl, headers=headers)
    requestCheckProgress = requestCheckResponse.json()["result"]["percentComplete"]
    print("Download is " + str(round(requestCheckProgress)) + " complete")

# Step 3: Downloading file
requestDownloadUrl = baseUrl + progressId + '/file'
requestDownload = requests.request("GET", requestDownloadUrl, headers=headers, stream=True)

# Step 4: Unzipping the file
zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(requestDownload.content)).extractall(mypath + "/MyQualtricsDownload")
print('Complete')
```

---

Comment: Define, "breaking everything" because it seems like commenting a couple of these lines will give you the result you want for the most part. What did you try?

Comment: Having done a little more tinkering here and there I think I have got it working for the most part. The only issue I'm now having is actually saving the downloaded file (zipped csv) to my downloads folder. Just disabling the unzipping code does not seem to help. I'm assuming the file must be somewhere on my PC (maybe just held in RAM), I just need to tell the computer to save it in downloads. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, to download to a specific folder, you should replace the '(mypath + "/MyQualtricsDownload")' with your desired folder location, e.g. 'C:\user\myname'.

Here is more information on the zipfile package: [ZipFile for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)